# Getting Vars Value From Function

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

I'm using this function;

```
function forums_fid()
{
    if (!defined('FORUMS_FID'))
    {
        $maktaba_fid = '14';
        $ask_question_fid = '9';
    }
    define('FORUMS_FID', 1);
}
```

I want to use variable's values in an another function, so for this I'm trying to use this code;

```
forums_fid();
$maktaba = '<a href="www.domain.com/forumdisplay.php?fid='.$maktaba_fid.'"><img src="./images/maktaba.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
$ask_question = '<a href="www.domain.com/newthread.php?fid='.$ask_question_fid.'"><img src="./images/ask-question.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
```

Bur unfortunately the variables are empty in this second code.

Please help!

Comment: you have to define the global variable scope outside the function.

Comment: Hi Parag, thanks for replying. Can you please give me any example of how to define a global variable scope. Please consider me a PHP noob.

Comment: @ParagTyagi: He has to define the global variable scope inside the function. Outside wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: My bad. Yes you are right. Just went through the docs.

Comment: @user2854563 change the method signature and pass $maktaba_fid, $ask_question_fid in method and you are done.

Comment: @user2854563: Try the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget what I said before. What you can do is define two empty variables (NULL) and declare them as global in the function, overwrite them with whatever you want and then use them. By the way, you have to put define() inside the if-clausel or PHP would throw an error.

```
function forums_fid()
{
    global $maktaba_fid, $ask_question_fid;

    if (!defined('FORUMS_FID'))
    {
        define('FORUMS_FID', 1);
        $maktaba_fid = '14';
        $ask_question_fid = '9';
    }
}

$maktaba_fid = NULL;
$ask_question_fid = NULL;
forums_fid();
$maktaba = '<a href="www.domain.com/forumdisplay.php?fid='.$maktaba_fid.'"><img src="./images/maktaba.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
$ask_question = '<a href="www.domain.com/newthread.php?fid='.$ask_question_fid.'"><img src="./images/ask-question.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
```

That's one way. The better way would be to actually return the values (as an array for example).

```
function forums_fid()
{
    if (!defined('FORUMS_FID'))
    {
        define('FORUMS_FID', 1);
        return array('maktaba_fid' => 14, 'ask_question_fid' => 9);
    }
}

$return = forums_fid();
$maktaba = '<a href="www.domain.com/forumdisplay.php?fid='.$return['maktaba_fid'].'"><img src="./images/maktaba.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
$ask_question = '<a href="www.domain.com/newthread.php?fid='.$return['ask_question_fid'].'"><img src="./images/ask-question.png" alt="" title=""></a>';
```

Comment: Oh yeah, just reread your question. I thought you want to use them inside the function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: when calling function 2nd time it will give an error : already defined

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Dunois. Your answer is exactly what I want !! Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **`$GLOBALS`** super variable.

```
function forums_fid()
{
    if (!defined('FORUMS_FID'))
    {
        $GLOBALS['maktaba_fid'] = '14';
        $GLOBALS['ask_question_fid'] = '9';
    }
    define('FORUMS_FID', 1);
}

forums_fid();
echo $GLOBALS['maktaba_fid'].PHP_EOL;
echo $GLOBALS['ask_question_fid'];
```

**DEMO:**

http://3v4l.org/k7TVA

**Documentation:**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: when calling function 2nd time it will give an error : already defined

Comment: used a one time solution now. `$GLOBALS` - super global variables.

Comment: Yeah, just throw everything in the super global variable so any script included before and after can use it! Seriously, there is no need to throw everything in the super global if you don't need the variable everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function forums_fid()
{
    global $maktaba_fid;
    global $ask_question_fid;
    if (!defined('FORUMS_FID'))
    {
        $maktaba_fid = '14';
        $ask_question_fid = '9';
        define('FORUMS_FID', 1);
    }

}
```